# Regex Replaces the text with users case text, how to maintain the actual word case

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am matching and replacing matching words with `<span>keyword</span>`,

Support users enter the search keyword in lower case as `united states` it matches the keyword and replaces it

**Actual String**

`String str = "This is United States Of America"`

**After Match & Replace function string is replaced with lower case match string as entered by the user**

`This is united states Of America` after match

I want to match and replace the string while maintaining the actual case of the matched word or words in the string or database

I use following code for this. How can i alter this so that my requirements are meant

```
    string pattern = @"(\b(?:" + Request["SearchKeyword"].ToString().Trim() + @")\b))";
    regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    result = regex.Replace(result, "<span class='highlight'>" + Request["SearchKeyword"].ToString() + "</span>",);
```

**Desired Output expected**
`This is United States Of America`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Match().Value` instead of the original request string.

Here is the code you can use:

```
var req = "united states";
var str = "This is United States Of America";
var pattern = @"((?<=^\p{P}*|\p{Zs})(?:" + req.ToString().Trim() + @")(?=\p{P}*$|\p{Zs}))";
var regx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var m = regx.Match(str);
var result = string.Empty;
if (m.Success)
   result = regx.Replace(str, "<span class='highlight'>" + m.Value + "</span>");
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:** (just in case)

Using a lambda, you can obtain the same result:

```
var regx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var result = regx.Replace(str, m => "<span class='highlight'>" + m.Value + "</span>");
```

It is safe even in case we have no match.

Comment: Tried it works like charm with the sample data need to do more test, How can i alter regex part so that it match words like lik `US` only not like `US-led`, at present it also match's part of `US-led` word how can i avaoid words which can have `-` at beginning or at end of the matched word

Comment: You need to use a different boundary. I'd use `\s|$` and `\s|^`: `var pattern = @"((?<=^|\s)(?:" + req.ToString().Trim() + @")(?=\s|$))";`

Comment: This breaks if word is at end like `You should visit US.` in this case it will break since you are using `\s`.

Comment: Try this one: `((?<=^\p{P}*|\p{Zs})(?:US)(?=\p{P}*$|\p{Zs}))` it will allow final (and leading just in case) punctuation, and is using Unicode spaces.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [another overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.100).aspx) of `Regex.Replace` method with MatchEvaluator

```
string str = "This is United States Of America";
string SearchKeyword = "united states";
string pattern = @"(\b(?:" + SearchKeyword.Trim() + @")\b)";
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var result = regex.Replace(str, new MatchEvaluator(m => "<span class='highlight'>" + m.ToString() + "</span>"));
```

Comment: I am not sure which one is better from performance point of view i thing your solution should be better.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, try both answers on input string `string str = "This is UNITED States Of America (United States)";` and you will see that Regex.Replace with MatchEvaluator is better (it doesn't change words!)